# Tensor product of an algebra and a field extension over a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K/k$ be a field extension and A a finite type (finitely generated) k-module. Further, let $R := A \otimes_k k (\cong A)$ and $L:=A\otimes_kK$. Is L always a finite type R-module?

It is known that (1) $dim_{Krull}(L)=dim_{Krull}(R)(=dim_{Krull}(A))$. But my instincts tell me to be cautious here:

Take $a_1,..., a_m$ generators for A (as $k$-module). Then any $a\otimes\alpha \in R$ can be expressed as $k$-linear combination of the $a_1\otimes1,...,a_m\otimes1$, and since the $a\otimes\alpha$ generate $R$, one obtains finitely many generators for $R$ (as $k$-module).
The trouble starts when $N:=[K:k]$ isn't finite:

$K$ can be viewed as $k^N$. But if $N$ isn't finite, I do not know how to find or how to see the existence of finitely many generators for $L$ as $R$-module.

Does anyone have a counter-example or an idea on how to demonstrate the assertion (should it actually hold)?

**EDIT** As suspected, the answer below shows that the statement doesn't hold. However, one has the following:

Using "Noether Normalisation", we obtain $k[X_1,...,X_n] \subset A$ is finite. This consequently tells us $k[X_1,...,X_n] \otimes_k K \rightarrow A \otimes_k K$ is injective and finite, thus yielding (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Take for example $k = \mathbb{Q}$, $K = \mathbb{R}$, and let $R = A = \mathbb{Q}$, which is indeed a finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-module. Then $L = R \otimes_k K = \mathbb{R}$ is not a finitely generated $R$-module, because it contains an infinite algebraically independent subset, e.g. $\{ \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7} \dots \}$.

However, if $K$ is a finitely generated $k$-module, then this is true. Suppose that $\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_d\}$ is a finite generating subset of $K$ as a $k$-module, i.e. every element of $K$ can be written as a polynomial in the $\lambda_i$ with coefficients in $k$. Then $\{ 1_R \otimes \lambda_1, \dots, 1_R \otimes \lambda_d \}$ is a generating subset of $L$ as an $R$-module.

Indeed every element $w$ of $L = R \otimes_k K$ can be written as a sum:
$$w = \sum r_i \otimes x_i$$
 with $r_i \in R$ and $x_i \in K$. Each $x_i$ can itself be written as $P_i(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_d)$, where $P_i \in k[X_1, \dots, X_d]$. It follows that
$$w = \sum r_i \cdot (1_R \otimes P_i(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_d)) = (\sum r_i P_i)(1_R \otimes \lambda_1, \dots, 1_R \otimes \lambda_d)$$
is a polynomial in terms of the $1_R \otimes \lambda_i$ with coefficients in $R$.